# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 Prompt different hierarchy levels with image prompts in one analysis

Tags: hierarchy, business-intelligence, prompt, dashboard, obiee

I want to prompt different elements of a hierarchy with one image prompt within a dashboard.

I.e.
[image]

I.e. the used analysis should prompt data for apple, when clicking on the apple image and it should prompt data for all fruits (apple + rest) when clicking on the fruits image.

Prompting either apples or fruits works fine, however combining this prompt does not work. So far I have tried alot: And/Or Levelx is prompted, case when xxx, union, ...

I.e.

[image]

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet Max, but is that screenshot just a fake or why are the coordinates the same for both areas?

Comment: Hi Chris, it is. I have just copied the first (fruit) column. Basically there are much more columns (with different coordinates and area titles). However, I think the problem at hand is displayed.

Comment: Ok, just was curious :)